# Understanding these Pointer Statements - Diagram

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand the following 3 code statements involving pointers (through image diagrams). If you can explain it without images that would also work

```
1- myobj *ptra = new myobj();
2- myobj *ptrb = new myobj[2]();
3- myobj **ptrc = new *myobj();
```

Here is my understanding , please correct me if I am wrong. Also the addresses in the image are totally imaginary (I know they don't make sense). My major concerns of understanding are basically with statement 2 and statement 3.

Statement 1 :
ptra (which is some address on the stack) points to an address on the heap

Statement 2:
ptra (which is some address on the stack) points to one address which has 2 parts ? Is that correct ?

[image]

Comment: #2 - It points to one address, but it can be moved to the next safely.

Comment: What does that mean , could you explain a little in detail

Comment: It means you can index it like an array of two integers, and it will initially point to the first element.

Comment: #2 - It create a consecutive space of `2 * sizeof(myobj)`, and the pointer `*ptrb` points to the lowest address of that space. The second element can be accessed by `ptrb[1]`. I am not sure if `*(ptrb + sizeof(myobj))` can do the work.

Comment: @Alvin: Pointer arithmetic takes into account the size of the type being pointed to -- so `ptrb[1]` is equivalent in this case to `*(ptrb + 1)`. The rest of your comment is spot on, +1.

Comment: I doubt these even compile...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is somewhat correct, though it seems like you mix too many things together and your diagram is missing details. Here is how I'd draw it for a few of the most simple cases...

Let's start from a simple case and take operator `new` out of the picture:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct myobj {
    int v;
};

int main()
{
    myobj obj[2];

    obj[0].v = 1;
    obj[1].v = 2;

    myobj *ptra = &obj[0];
    myobj *ptrb = &obj[1];
    myobj **ptrc = &ptrb;

    printf("obj size is: %lu\n", sizeof(myobj));
    printf("pointer size: %lu\n", sizeof(void *));

    printf("obj[0] address: %p\n", (void *)&obj[0]);
    printf("obj[1] address: %p\n", (void *)&obj[1]);
    printf("ptra address is %p, it points to %p\n", (void *)&ptra, (void *)ptra);
    printf("ptrb address is %p, it points to %p\n", (void *)&ptrb, (void *)ptrb);
    printf("ptrc address is %p, it points to %p\n", (void *)&ptrc, (void *)ptrc);
}
```

The above program will output something like this:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -o test ./test.cpp 
$ ./test 
obj size is: 4
pointer size: 8
obj[0] address: 0x7fff5b73dbc0
obj[1] address: 0x7fff5b73dbc4
ptra address is 0x7fff5b73dbb8, it points to 0x7fff5b73dbc0
ptrb address is 0x7fff5b73dbb0, it points to 0x7fff5b73dbc4
ptrc address is 0x7fff5b73dba8, it points to 0x7fff5b73dbb0
```

Which corresponds to the following simple layout in memory:

[image: simple data layout]

So what's different from your drawing? Addresses of pointers and objects. If the pointer itself is placed at address 0, then the next pointer cannot be placed at address 1 simply because a pointer itself takes more space, and so other data can only be placed at `0 + sizeof(void*)` address. For objects, the next address is greater by at least the size of the object itself (i.e. `sizeof(myobj)`).

When dynamic allocation gets involved, the picture changes a bit. For example, when operator "new" is used to allocate objects like this:

```
myobj *ptra = new myobj();
myobj *ptrb = new myobj();
myobj **ptrc = &ptrb;
```

... you can think of a memory layout like this:

[image: dynamic memory layout]

Now, a pointer to another pointer (**) is nothing but a pointer that points to the first of one or more pointers that point to object(s). Easy, right? Any you can have pointer to a pointer to a pointer... Anyway, with a dynamically allocated pointer to pointers, like this:

```
myobj *ptra = new myobj();
myobj *ptrb = new myobj();
myobj **ptrc = new myobj*[2];
ptrc[0] = ptra;
ptrc[1] = ptrb;
```

The memory layout could look like this:

[image: with pointer to pointer(s)]

By the way, you have an error in your line #3 here - `myobj **ptrc = new *myobj();`. It should be `myobj **ptrc = new myobj*();`.

To address your later questions, below is a diagram depicting the result of `myobj *ptrb = new myobj[2]();` expression where you have a pointer that points to two objects allocated dynamically. The pointer itself points to the first object out of two allocated:

[image: myobj *ptrb = new myobj[2]();]

And one more time about pointers to pointers so that you can see the difference. Consider the following code:

```
struct myobj {
    int v;
};

int main()
{
    myobj *ptra = new myobj[2]();
    myobj *ptrb = new myobj[4]();
    myobj **ptrc = new myobj*[2];

    ptrc[0] = ptra;
    ptrc[1] = ptrb;

    ptrc[0][0].v = 1;
    ptrc[0][1].v = 2;
    ptrc[1][0].v = 3;
    ptrc[1][1].v = 4;
    ptrc[1][2].v = 5;
    ptrc[1][3].v = 6;
}
```

It will create the following layout:

[image]

As you can see, the stack contains three pointers (they are also objects) that are not dynamically allocated. This is a result of declaration:

```
myobj *ptra;
myobj *ptrb;
myobj **ptrc;
```

Then, three different things are allocated with "new":

1. Two objects of type `myobj` are allocated with expression `new myobj[2]()`, the address to the first of those objects is stored in pointer `ptra`.
2. Four objects of type `myobj` are allocated with expression `new myobj[4]()`, the result of that expression is address of the first out of four objects, and it is stored in pointer "ptrb".
3. Two pointers are allocated with with expression `new myobj*[2]`. The result of that expression is an address of the first out of two pointers. That address is stored in variable `ptrc`.

Now, those two allocated pointers (in "Block C") point "nowhere". So just for the sake of example we make them point to the same objects as `ptra` and `ptrb` are pointing by copying pointers "by value":

```
ptrc[0] = ptra;
ptrc[1] = ptrb;
```

That easy!

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you for the effort! And, do you mind saying what you used to draw the diagrams?

Comment: @Meysam: Thanks. The diagrams are made using Omni Graffle (http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/).

Comment: Hi , great post - you typed in printf("pointer size: %lu\n", sizeof(void *)); Is that missing something ?

Comment: @VladLazarenko  Also could you explain `myobj *ptrb = new myobj[2]();` using the diagram , Will ptrb in this case point to just one address or multiple addresses ?

Comment: @AdamZedan: I've added two more pics to address that. I am not sure what do you mean by "Is that missing something ?" though.

Comment: That answers the question. Thanks for the great explanation